# How do I display the dynamics of currency exchange rates?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

My task is to implement the ability to display the dynamics of currency exchange rates, by selecting the start date of the period and the end date?
Maybe something like this would suit me:

[image]

But I'm a newbie and don't know what this component is...

I get data from an external API as well. I'm also already in the process of writing a scheduler to automatically get data at a specific time each day. I have an `Exchange_Rate__c` object that has certain currency rates as fields: `USD__c, CAD__c, EUR__c, GBP__c`. At the moment, I already have an `APEX` method that gets data in the form of `List<Exchange_Rate__c>` from the database and I need to decide how to display this data in my component.

I will be grateful for any help and advice. What is better to apply in my case?

Comment: To achieve something like this you would need to store the data in custom object and then create a report/dashboard on it. Your data can come either from Salesforce (org exchange rates - if that is what you want - DatedConversionRate) or an external API/system. So as first step you need to identify where you data is/will be coming from and in second step, you need to write an apex class (Scheduler maybe) which runs at specific intervals, maybe daily or weekly and capture this data. This is one way of achieving this. Let us know if you are stuck somewhere specific, we would love to help.

Comment: Thank you, I added an additional question to clarify what functionality I have.

Answer (score 1):

There's no native component we can use to render a chart*. However, you can easily use something like [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) in a [component](https://www.forcetrails.com/2021/01/build-candlestick-chart-lwc-with-d3js.html) (not my post, but really informative!). Once you've gotten your data mapped out correctly, it's simply a matter of putting the data into the chart. You can also find tons of other examples out there on the Internet if you look around a bit. If you get stuck during the development process, let us know, we'll be more than happy to help you out.

* *As of Summer '21, this may change in the future.*

Comment: Looks like link is broken in your answer.

Comment: @javanoob Yeah, apparently I missed ctrl in ctrl-v. Give me a sec... done. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I forgot to mention that I'm currently working with Aura Components, not LWC.

Comment: I also tried to search on the Internet, but due to the fact that English is not my native language, it is still difficult for me and I have not found anything suitable yet...

Comment: @uniqueuser Doing it in Aura is pretty much the same as in LWC, just implementation details change. Check out `<ltng:require>` for how to load a script in Aura.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try.